# ExpandableListView array lists won't stay in the order I put them

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap, expandablelistview

I'm making use of the ExpandableListView and I have a few lists set in an array lists.
I set them to be in a certain order which is:

```
company, day of the week, posh vehicles, topgear vehicles
```

but what ever I do the order reverts to

```
posh vehicles, company, days of the week, topgear vehicles
```

Can anybody help me figure out the problem here is the code I'm using for the stringArray?

```
 public static HashMap<String, List<String>> getData() {

    HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    List<String> listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("Company");
    listDataHeader.add("Please pick a day");
    listDataHeader.add("Posh Vehicles");
    listDataHeader.add("TopGear Vehicles");

    List<String> CompanyName = new ArrayList<>();
    CompanyName.add("Posh limos");
    CompanyName.add("TopGear limos");

    List<String> daysOftheWeek = new ArrayList<>();
    daysOftheWeek.add("Monday");
    daysOftheWeek.add("Tuesday");
    daysOftheWeek.add("Wednesday");
    daysOftheWeek.add("Thursday");
    daysOftheWeek.add("Thursday");
    daysOftheWeek.add("Friday");
    daysOftheWeek.add("Saturday");
    daysOftheWeek.add("Sunday");

    List<String> poshvehicles = new ArrayList<>();
    poshvehicles.add("Posh H2 limo");
    poshvehicles.add("Iveco party bus");
    poshvehicles.add("Merc party bus ");
    poshvehicles.add("Party coach");

    List<String> topGearVehicles = new ArrayList<>();
    topGearVehicles.add("TopGear H2 limo");
    topGearVehicles.add("TopGear party bus");

    expandableListDetail.put(listDataHeader.get(0),CompanyName);
    expandableListDetail.put(listDataHeader.get(1),daysOftheWeek);
    expandableListDetail.put(listDataHeader.get(2),poshvehicles);
    expandableListDetail.put(listDataHeader.get(3),topGearVehicles);

    return expandableListDetail;
```

Comment: Another hint: There is no point in remembering weekday names in your logic. Instead, you should be using Javas date/calendar APIs - they can do that for you.

Comment: thanks as always @GhostCat will take a look at the duplicate question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HashMap` doesn't keep the insertion order.

You can use a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) instead (which extends `HashMap`):

```
Map<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

I also used the interface name on the left side `Map` and the diamond operator (`<>`) that works if you have at least Java 7.

Comment: I feel tempted to downvote on answering that obvious "dup" question; but won't as you at least put in that nice detail about using the diamond operator ;-)